# Cannot compare typedef string with ==

Tags: c++

In my program, I did

```
typedef std::string newName
```

I have a method that requires me to insert a newName into an array of type newName as long as there aren't any existing copies. To do this, I have to check every element of the array.

```
bool insert(newName insertThis)
{
    if(arrayName[i] == insertThis)
        return false;
    ...
}
```

Compiler says it can't compare two newName objects with "==" even though I used typedef to indicate that newName is the same as a string.

Comment: post a complete but minimal example

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I always think your name is a link to something.

Comment: And post the actual error message.

Comment: Probably arrayName[i] is not std::string

Comment: Is this related to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227789/trying-to-compare-two-strings-with-causes-error? If yes, please post some minimal example this time.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::string abc;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 abc a;
 abc b;

 if (a == b)
 {
  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
 }

 system("pause");

 return 0;
} Works perfectly. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Benjamin omg, now the OP will lose all of his / her remaining rep!

Comment: A more useful naming convention is `bool insert(std::string newName)`. (And you should have recognized this symptom from yesterday.)

Answer (score 8):

You still have to include `<string>`

Comment: +1 for mind reading his complete code.